# vue js on click goes to template in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

In laravel I have a vue.js main view template, what i want is when i click on main template this displays the child model

```
//my main template
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li @click="chatWith()"></li>
        </ul>    
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        chatWith(){
            return {
                template:<conversation-with></conversation-with>
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

but is not working, another code is working on click, but goes to template isn't

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to route to a new page you need to create a route that points to that template somehow. You can either set up that template on a blade and use laravel's routing in web.php to create a route for it, then link to it like a normal `<a href="/chatWith">`, or you can similarly create a route using vue router instead, which would allow you to have single-page apps with better routing control.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing (make sure it's your correct laravel version)
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/

if you need it to be some kind of modal or something that's another story though